# scaffold routes do not expect to have id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run rake routes in rails 5 app I see the following urls available:

```
edit_articles     GET    /articles/edit(.:format)    articles#edit
articles          GET    /articles(.:format)         articles#show
                  PATCH  /articles(.:format)         articles#update
                  PUT    /articles(.:format)         articles#update
                  DELETE /articles(.:format)         articles#destroy
```

this whay when I create a link_to a resource I need to include id param in it like:

```
link_to article.name, manager_articles_path(id: article.id)
```

instead of rails 4 way:

```
link_to article.name, manager_articles_path(article)
```

how can I make rails 5 routes to behave as rails 4 ones?

```
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Thank you.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  resource :articles
end
```

Comment: Hey Please show your `routes.rb` code for articles.

Comment: @ABPrime updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rails `resource` and `resources` is not same.

**resource**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without
>   referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show
>   the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use
>   a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the
>   show action.

**routes**

```
 edit_articles     GET    /articles/edit(.:format)    articles#edit
 articles          GET    /articles(.:format)         articles#show
                   PATCH  /articles(.:format)         articles#update
                   PUT    /articles(.:format)         articles#update
                   DELETE /articles(.:format)         articles#destroy
```

**resources**

resources is used as a way to handle generic requests on any item, then a singular resource is a way to work on the current item at hand.

**routes**

```
articles     GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Ohh, facepalm, one 's'.. :) Thanks.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: It happens.